# References and Object Slicing

Tags: c++, object-slicing

I don't have my Effective C++ with me and this is bugging me so much that I have to ask for my own sanity.  Given

```
class Foo : public Bar{}

void MyFunc(Bar &_input);
```

If I pass in a `Foo`, am I tangling with the [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c) problem or have I avoided it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Not a problem, because you're passing in a reference. You're not creating a new object, just letting MyFunc access the original object.

Comment: Thanks.  This was driving me crazy.

Answer (score 6):

Since you are passing the reference - **no**, unless you later assign to an instance of `Bar`.

Answer (score 2):

Slicing is only a problem when you cast an object to its parent class.  There is no slicing when you cast pointers or references.